# How to copy a shell script to created job in jenkins using job dsl plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have some shell script as like below

```
echo $BUILD_NUMBER
echo $GIT_BRANCH
echo $SUNNY
```

How to copy the snippet to created job using dsl script?
I know we can achieve it by `shell(readFileFromWorkspace('build.sh'))`

But is there anyway copy the script using dsl script instead of providing using a .sh file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to configure a shell step.

1. you can use a script from the seed job's workspace as in your example

   ```
   job('example') {
     steps {
       shell(readFileFromWorkspace('build.sh'))
     }
   }
   ```
2. you can use an inline script

   ```
   job('example') {
     steps {
       shell('''echo $BUILD_NUMBER
   echo $GIT_BRANCH
   echo $SUNNY''')
     }
   }
   ```
3. you can call a script in the generated job's workspace

   ```
   job('example') {
     steps {
       shell('./build.sh')
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: the third option can only work, when the build.sh is copied into the workspace of the generated job? And that is (i think) exactly the question.